# Create multiple text files for selected data on excel using vba scripting in single click

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

I am using the code below to generate the single file for selected range and considering the first cell in the selected range as file name. Please find the image below for more details[[This image shows the selected range,Consider K column(Firstline) and N Column( Lastline) to be in one file and other set of 1st and last line in other file ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TlxX.jpg)[this image shows the print file for a single file this is the way m currently using for generating files.I need to create more 30k files so please help me to create more files in single click considering the first and last line as header and footer for the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmdDW.jpg)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer, path As String, filename, filename2 As String
path = "D:\Watchlist-Files\"

filename = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value
filename2 = Left(Mid(filename, 32, 99), Len(Mid(filename, 32, 99)) - 2)

myFile = path & filename2

Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value


If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Print #1, cellValue
Else
    Print #1, cellValue,

End If


   Next j
Next i


Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the question ? are you getting an error ? which line ?

Comment: i am not getting any error, in the above code it is used for generating single file, i need to create more files in a single click

Comment: in the selected range it should consider a cell as reference for creating a file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is using a Loop that scans rows in a range that consists of Columns K:N (according to your attached screen-shots).

**Assumptions made**: your `FirstLine` is in **Column K**, and it's the marker of the start position of copying the first cell in the first row.
Your `LastLine` is in **Column N**, and it's the marker of the last cell to copy, this is why I am closing the file once it is found.

**Edit 1**: added a `Msgbox` to allow the user selection of exporting the entire range or not. In case the user selected **NO**, then a second `InputBox` appears that allows the user to enter manually the last row number to export.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile                          As String
Dim rng                             As Range
Dim cellValue                       As Variant
Dim i                               As Long
Dim j                               As Long
Dim LastRow                         As Long
Dim path                            As String
Dim filename                        As String
Dim response                        As Boolean

path = "D:\Watchlist-Files\"

response = MsgBox("Do you want to Export the entire Range ? ", vbYesNo)
' Export the entire Range
If response = vbYes Then
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
Else  ' enter in the inputbox the last row number you want to export
    LastRow = InputBox("Enter Last Row Number you wsnt to Export")
End If
Set rng = Range("K2:N" & LastRow)

For i = 2 To LastRow

    ' Column K holds the file name
    If Cells(i, 11) <> "" Then
        filename = Left(Mid(Cells(i, 11).Value, 32, 99), Len(Mid(Cells(i, 11).Value, 32, 99)) - 2)

        myFile = path & filename
        Open myFile For Output As #1
    End If

    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = Cells(i, 10 + j).Value

        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Print #1, cellValue
            ' found LastLine >> close the file
            If Not cellValue = "" Then
                Close #1
            End If
        Else
            Print #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit 2**: Added new code below (to keep the first option valid). The user needs to confirm that every selection he makes start and ends with `FirstLine` and `LastLine` , there is no error handling.

*Option Explicit Section*

```
Option Explicit

Dim filename                        As String
Dim path                            As String
Dim myFile                          As String
Dim rng                             As Range
Dim j                               As Long
```

*Public Sub CommandButton1_Click*

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastRow                         As Long
Dim Sel_Range                       As Long
Dim response                        As Boolean
Dim rowStart()                      As Long
Dim rowFinish()                     As Long

path = "D:\Watchlist-Files\"

response = MsgBox("Do you want to Export only the Selected Range ? ", vbYesNo)
If response = True Then
    Set rng = Selection

    ReDim rowStart(1 To Selection.Areas.Count)
    ReDim rowFinish(1 To Selection.Areas.Count)

    For Sel_Range = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
        rowStart(Sel_Range) = Selection.Areas(Sel_Range).Row
        rowFinish(Sel_Range) = Selection.Areas(Sel_Range).Row + Selection.Areas(Sel_Range).Rows.Count - 1

        Call CreateTextFiles(rowStart(Sel_Range), rowFinish(Sel_Range))
    Next Sel_Range

Else ' export the entire Range in Columns K:N
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("K2:N" & lastRow)
    Call CreateTextFiles(2, lastRow)
End If
```

*Sub CreateTextFiles(Sel_StartRow As Long, Sel_FinishRow As Long)* - new routine to allow handling of multiple Ranges selection

```
Sub CreateTextFiles(Sel_StartRow As Long, Sel_FinishRow As Long)

Dim i                               As Long
Dim cellValue                       As Variant

For i = Sel_StartRow To Sel_FinishRow

    ' Column K holds the file name
    If Cells(i, 11) <> "" Then
        filename = Left(Mid(Cells(i, 11).Value, 32, 99), Len(Mid(Cells(i, 11).Value, 32, 99)) - 2)

        myFile = path & filename
        Open myFile For Output As #1
    End If

    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = Cells(i, 10 + j).Value

        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Print #1, cellValue
            ' found LastLine >> close the file
            If Not cellValue = "" Then
                Close #1
            End If
        Else
            Print #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot .... Awesome,,.....thanks for the explanation too .. m just beginner in vba scripting...

Comment: its not holding my selection range it keeps creating for all values in those 4 columns .... please make this for selected ranges too

Comment: @sivavikas you don't want the export for the entire range of Columns K:N ? you want to select a certain range manually ?

Comment: the code you gave is pretty use in one case, i need to create for some range manualy, because m having more than 30k files to generate.

Comment: @sivavikas see edited code, allows you to select if you want to export the entire range, or you can enter in an `InpotBox` the last row number you want to export

Comment: in this case  m not able to skip the rows in between my selection, if i filter values from row 1to 60 and 1000 to 1600 i want this data to be made in file.But in our case files are generating till 1600 th row

Comment: Thanks a lot for the codes ...everything works fine......catch you later..